# Import error when using pandas for fsspec in python?

Tags: python, pandas, import, tox, fsspec

I had an issue where pandas would report an import error, upon attempting to use a buffer from io's StringIO class, during the use of read_csv() from pandas.

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you showed the code you executed and the full error andvtraceback resulting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing fsspec (an optional package for pandas) alone is not enough for pandas to be able to import fsspec. The dependecies for fsspec need also be installed, I don't know why the maintainers are not handling this with install.py, but here we are. I'll send them a message, but if you find your self in this condition, try:

`pip install tox tox-conda`

Comment: I am not sure how your solution of installing `tox` and `tox-conda` has anything to do with `fsspec` and `read_csf()`... could you elaborate?

Comment: I thought I explained it well enough, my fault: When you install fsspec, the dependencies tox, and tox-conda are not installed. You can check the pyPI entry to see the instructions for using the library. AFAICT: using pandas with a buffer containing a bytestring, requires the optional package fsspec. fsspec failed to work on my macintosh without manually installing tox and tox-conda. Does that track a bit better?

Comment: Thank you! I guess this depends what you try to do. From reading the docs of fspring, both tox and tox-conda are dev and test dependencies, not runtime or build dependencies. Anyway, glad you figured it out 